# What does `sleep` with multiple arguments mean?

Tags: coreutils, sleep

I was wondering what differences are between

```
sleep 1 2 3
```

and

```
sleep 6
```

?

They seem the same. Thanks.

Comment: It is not recommended to use vondor specific feaures like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's like this so that you can use different time units together

```
sleep  183965
```

same effect as

```
sleep 2d 3h 6m 5s
```

But this second one is easier for humans to understand as two days, three hours, six minutes, and five seconds.